# What could be preventing VSCode showing run tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

I have been using tasks.json in Ionic and Ember projects.

In one specific project trying to open the list of tasks with Tasks|Run Task... does not work - the little blue loading marker scrolls across the bottom of the window and after a short while the window just closes.

Anybody know where I can start to look?

I have tried copying the exact same tasks.json file from other working projects so it is not a typo in that file.

(VSCode 1.15.1, Node 7.4.0, Windows 10)

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the dev console that could be related (Help -> Toggle Developer Tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty broccoli tmp folder!

It seems a lot of people find the broccoli /tmp folder filling up fast! Mine was 2.95GB just for the ember tutorial project! I have to keep manually deleting thousands of files from here, and each time my tasks start working again!

As the tmp folder fills up through repeated rebuilds the tasks menu seems to get slower and slower.

Answer (score 1):

> open the list of tasks with Tasks|Run Task... does not work

More generally, a slow task provider can prevent the list to show up.

See [VSCode 1.43](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/df0d617fee4f2f3802c318c8faefa3bad7801907/release-notes/v1_43.md#task-quick-pick-updates) (Feb. 2020, 3 years later)

> ### Task quick pick updates
>
> The task quick pick, shown when the Run Task command is executed, has been updated to show you which task providers are still running.
>
> If you don't need tasks from that provider, the "**`Stop Detecting`**" button will immediately show you the tasks that have been detected so far **so you don't have to wait for any slow task providers**.
>
> [image: Tasks Stop Detecting -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_43/tasks_stop_detecting.gif]